# how to ignore a test result in NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit

I know I can ignore a whole function, but what if I run a [TestCaseSource] in a test and I want in the xml to have result="ignored" only for certain value?

```
    [Test, TestCaseSource("divider")]
    static public void NUnitWriter(string commandLine)
    {
        int errorLevel;
        errorLevel = executeCmd (commandLine);

        Assert.AreNotEqual (0, errorLevel, writeInXml);
    }
```

and now before the assert I'd like to make something like this :

```
if (errorLevel == 63)
{
     //then how to write result="ignore" in the xml?
}
```

Comment: testing it, but I guess it is indeed a duplicate

Comment: this links adds more information to the problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712528/how-to-ignore-a-run-test/30713522#30713522