# how to ignore a RUN test

Tags: nunit

`Assert.Ignore` is used to ignore a test in Nunit.

However, in my case I run tests, and if they have, for example, error code 2, I may choose to ignore the result for a while, but I still want it to be counted in the number of run test. But is there just a way to say the result is ignored, neither a failure or a success.

In the *.xml I'd like to have

result="Ignored"

**executed="True"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use for now Assert.Inconclusive(), executed="True", so it's the closest to what I wanted.

If someone finds better, feel free to post.